# Silverlight or WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, silverlight

I’m about to start work on a new LOB application which is mainly forms over data. I am going to use either WPF or Silverlight but am not sure which technology to use. Silverlight seems to have everything I need with the bonus of being cross platform as well. Is there any reason why I should use WPF in this context? or is Silverlight the way to go for these sort of applications?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF vs Silverlight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944608/wpf-vs-silverlight)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If Silverlight seems to have everything you need I'd say go for it!

You could start out writing a simple prototype where you address your biggest concerns. If Silverlight handles those tasks you got your confirmation, and can proceed writing the whole application in Silverlight.

Silverlight is catching up on WPF, and when [Silverlight 4](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/11/18/whats-new-in-silverlight-4-complete-guide-new-features.aspx) is released you can solve many of the things you needed WPF for before.

Check out these other questions:

- [WPF vs Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944608/wpf-vs-silverlight)
- [WPF vs Silverlight 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666058/wpf-vs-silverlight-3-0)
- [What does WPF still have to offer over SL4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758070/what-does-wpf-still-have-to-offer-over-silverlight-4)

Answer (score 2):

Deployment is one consideration. Silverlight is browser based (requires plugin to be setup), WPF isn't so required setting up on everyone's computer.

There is no one right answer - it depends on how the application is to be used, what the architecture is like etc...

Comment: Well, you can use .xbap's, which are hosted in browser WPF apps.